# Trying to write a C++ program that lists all the polite numbers in the upper value

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, if the user enters the number 21, I want all the polite numbers listed. so for 21, the output would be 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21. I am new for loops and I am having a difficult time trying to get this to work. I cant include any global variables for this assignment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `n` is never initailised. Reading from an uninitialised variable is undefined behaviour, and should be generally avoided. Your code also talks about fibonacci numbers and seems to use the formula for them. After a quick googling you can find that numbers which are not powers of two are polite, so you just have to check whether the number is, and not print that in this case.

Comment: Hello Lala. I have fixed my code to not print numbers that are powers of two. This still displays numbers that are impolite, such as 9 and 32 when I run my program. It also doesn't display some polite numbers. I have edited my post so you can see my updates.

Comment: 9 is polite as far as I can tell (2+3+4) and 32 is a power of two (2^5)

Comment: In the past few days I've seen at least 5 questions about polite numbers with the exact same input  handling code. I am curious: is this an assignment where you are encouraged to use Stack overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are just excluding the numbers which are squares, which would not produce the right answer.
You can either create an array upto upValue with initial value set to 0 and mark all the powers of 2 as 1 using this for loop:

```
for(int j=1;j<=upValue;j*=2){
    arr[j]=1;
}
```

now you have flagged all the powers of two and then iterate over the all values from 1 to upValue and print the ones that are set to 0;

Answer (score 0):

The following program does what you want it to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
   
    void politeNo(int input)
    {
        // Print all initial input Polite number
        for (int n = 1; n <= input; ++n)
        {

            // Calculate nth Polite number
            int result = (int)(n +
                (log((n + (log(n) /
                    log(2))))) /
                log(2));

            // Display calculated result
            std::cout << " " << result;
            if (result == input){break; }
        }
    }
int main()
{
    int upValue = 0;
    std::cout<<" What is the upper value ?";
    std::cin >> upValue; //Stores user input into upValue

    while (upValue < 1) //Validate user input of upper limit
    {
        std::cout << "What is the upper value? (must be an integer > 0) ";
        std::cin >> upValue;
    }
    politeNo(upValue);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 17 18 19 20 21
```

Comment: May I suggest you to consider what numbers are *not* polite? You'll probably find out a much easier (and numerically robust) way to accomplish this task. BTW, please note that since C++11 you could use [std::log2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2).